# Electric field from DFT calculations in Vasp

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, density-functional-theory

This is a naive question. I am studying the surface-adsorbate systems using DFT calculations implemented in VASP. By setting LVHAR = True, I obtain LOCPOT which contains [information](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/LOCPOT) about the ionic and electrostatic potential.

I would like to clarify whether this information is actually the **electrostatic potential** or the **electrostatic potential energy**. My source of confusion is that VaspWiki states that the electrostatic potential is written in terms of eV, which indicates it should be an energetic quantity.

Comment: Implementation details of computational tasks are [off-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site: “While computational physics is on topic, we are not a programming site. If your question is about implementing computational code - in particular, if it's about writing, compiling, debugging or optimizing code, or about a specific language or library - then it is off topic.” This question is about a specific library.

Comment: The VASP-forum would be an appropriate place to ask this question.